# How to show printer setting instead printing pdf in crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

1. when pop up a page to show crystal report, press printer button will pop up print as pdf, but expect printer?

Edit :  left hand corner printer icon button do not pop up a printer dialog to print paper, but pop up a dialog titled print as pdf

when i try to answer this question stackoverflow's answer can not type in IE6,
i answer here  -> CrystalReportViewer1.PrintMode = CrystalDecisions.Web.PrintMode.ActiveX;

1. How to close left hand side list panel, can not find HasXXXX to close it?

`CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;
    CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleParameterPanelButton = false;
    CrystalReportViewer1.HasDrilldownTabs = false;

    CrystalReportViewer1.HasZoomFactorList = false;
    CrystalReportViewer1.HasPrintButton = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is this in ASP.NET ? When you click the print button it will display the list of available printers on the client not the server. I'm not sure I fully understand your question.
2. You need to set the `DisplayGroupTree` property to `false`  There is also a `ShowGroupTreeButton` property which toggles whether the user is allowed to show or hide the Group Tree Pane.

   ```
       // C# Code
       // Hide the Group Tree Pane
       this.crystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
       // Hide the Group Tree Panel Toolbar Button
       this.crystalReportViewer1.ShowGroupTreeButton = false;
   ```

**EDIT**

I think you need to set the `ToolPanelView` to None or `null` for CR2008

Comment: It is asp .net, no CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree How to do?

Comment: no CrystalReportViewer1.ShowGroupTreeButton. First question is pop up crystal report, the printer button is showing print as pdf not printer

Comment: There is a printer icon button at the left hand side corner, but it do not show printer dialog to print paper

Comment: no CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree, i am using crystal report 2008, will it be affected?

Comment: CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;  Second question is Success.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your second question (hide the group tree/left side panel) is:

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None;
```